# Gracefully Shutdown Gorilla Server

Tags: go, webserver, channel, sigint, gorilla

I'm building a server in go using gorilla multiplexer library found in https://github.com/gorilla/mux.
The problem is, I want it to gracefully shutdown when I'm using Ctrl+C, or when there is a specific API call, for example "/shutdown".

I already know that in Go 1.8, graceful shutdown is already implemented. But how to combine it with gorilla multiplexer? Also, how to combine it with SIGINT signal?

Can anyone show me how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Channel can be used to capture shutdown request through API call (`/shutdown`) or interrupt signal (`Ctrl+C`).

1. Embed `http.Server` into a custom struct, so we can call [http Server.Shutdown](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Shutdown) later
2. Add channel field (`shutdownReq`) for passing shutdown request from API call `/shutdown`
3. Register http handlers including `/shutdown` in `gorilla/mux`'s router, then assign the router to `http.Server.Handler`
4. Register `os.Interrupt/syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM` handler
5. Use `select` to capture shutdown request through API call or `interrupt` signal
6. Perform clean shutdown by calling `Server.Shutdown`

Below is the example code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync/atomic"
    "syscall"
    "time"

    "os"
    "os/signal"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type myServer struct {
    http.Server
    shutdownReq chan bool
    reqCount    uint32
}

func NewServer() *myServer {
    //create server
    s := &myServer{
        Server: http.Server{
            Addr:         ":8080",
            ReadTimeout:  10 * time.Second,
            WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
        },
        shutdownReq: make(chan bool),
    }

    router := mux.NewRouter()

    //register handlers
    router.HandleFunc("/", s.RootHandler)
    router.HandleFunc("/shutdown", s.ShutdownHandler)

    //set http server handler
    s.Handler = router

    return s
}

func (s *myServer) WaitShutdown() {
    irqSig := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(irqSig, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    //Wait interrupt or shutdown request through /shutdown
    select {
    case sig := <-irqSig:
        log.Printf("Shutdown request (signal: %v)", sig)
    case sig := <-s.shutdownReq:
        log.Printf("Shutdown request (/shutdown %v)", sig)
    }

    log.Printf("Stoping http server ...")

    //Create shutdown context with 10 second timeout
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    //shutdown the server
    err := s.Shutdown(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Shutdown request error: %v", err)
    }
}

func (s *myServer) RootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello Gorilla MUX!\n"))
}

func (s *myServer) ShutdownHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Shutdown server"))

    //Do nothing if shutdown request already issued
    //if s.reqCount == 0 then set to 1, return true otherwise false
    if !atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32(&s.reqCount, 0, 1) {
        log.Printf("Shutdown through API call in progress...")
        return
    }

    go func() {
        s.shutdownReq <- true
    }()
}

func main() {
    //Start the server
    server := NewServer()

    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        err := server.ListenAndServe()
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Listen and serve: %v", err)
        }
        done <- true
    }()

    //wait shutdown
    server.WaitShutdown()

    <-done
    log.Printf("DONE!")
}
```

**Note**: Please watch [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4674) which is related to gracefull shutdown.

Comment: thanks for providing this example. what does the 10 second shutdown context do?

Answer (score 0):

A variation of the original question - how to shut down in a unit test? Watching for an OS signal is not needed, timeouts aren't needed, and so there's less to synchronize. Also, there's another issue - a unit test usually has to wait for the server to start listening before doing its test.

Here's @putu's answer simplified for this purpose.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "testing"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type (
    myServer struct {
        ctx      context.Context
        srv      http.Server
        stopping uint32
        err      error
        wg       sync.WaitGroup
    }
)

func newServer(ctx context.Context, port int) (s *myServer) {
    s = &myServer{
        ctx: ctx,
        srv: http.Server{
            Addr: fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port),
        },
    }

    // make the routes
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", s.getRoot)

    s.srv.Handler = router
    return
}

func (s *myServer) getRoot(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // example route
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}

func (s *myServer) start() (err error) {
    addr := s.srv.Addr
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    s.wg.Add(1)

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("Server started")
        err = s.srv.Serve(ln)
        if err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            s.err = err
        }
        s.wg.Done()
    }()

    return
}

func (s *myServer) stop() error {
    if atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32(&s.stopping, 0, 1) {
        s.srv.Shutdown(s.ctx)
        fmt.Println("Server stopped")
    }
    s.wg.Wait()
    return s.err
}

func TestMockServer(t *testing.T) {
    s := newServer(context.Background(), 8000)
    err := s.start()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    // ...do a test that makes use of the mock server...
    _, err = http.Get("http://localhost:8000")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = s.stop()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```